# Validator throwing error

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have the following RegularExpressionValidator on one of my pages:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="InKindTextBox"
                                        ErrorMessage="The value entered for 'Cash' must be in a number format.   Examples: 500.00, 500, $500, $50,000 or $500.00" 
                                        ValidationExpression="(?n:(^\$?(?!0,?\d)\d{1,3}(?=(?<1>,)|(?<1>))(\k<1>\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?)$)" >
```

But when it tries to validate it throws the error below from one of my dynamic JS pages.

[image]

When I run this regex through [regex texter](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) it works fine.  Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses a different regexp syntax than .NET. See, for example, [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Quote from MSDN's [RegularExpressionValidator page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx):

> The regular-expression validation
>   implementation is slightly different
>   on the client than on the server. On
>   the client, JScript regular-expression
>   syntax is used. On the server,
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
>   syntax is used. Since JScript regular
>   expression syntax is a subset of
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex 
>   syntax, it is recommended that JScript
>   regular-expression syntax be used in
>   order to yield the same results on
>   both the client and the server.

**Update:** A thorough comparison of regular expression flavors across many languages including .NET and JavaScript can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

**Update 2:**
Below is a regex that should validate currency input using jScript compliant regex:

```
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="CashTextBox" ValidationGroup="vld_Insert"
                                    ErrorMessage="The value entered for 'Cash' must be in a number format.  Examples: 5000, 5000.00, 5,000 or $5,000.00" 
                                    ValidationExpression="^\s*\$?\s*(?!\d{4,},)(\d|\d{1,3},(?=\d{3})(?!\d{4}))*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$">
```

Comment: Any chance you'd know how to convert my regex to a jScrpt regular expression?  :)

Comment: Updated with a link to a comparison page — good helper to get your regexp translated properly. Also, checkout their regexp tools. Their powergrep is a very useful app.

Answer (score 3):

I think your regex is too complicated anyway. I'd use something simpler like

```
^[1-9]\d*(\.\d*)?$
```

That says no leading 0, at least one number before the decimal point, and an optional decimal point followed by more numbers.

**Edit**

```
^\$?([1-9]\d?\d?((,\d{3})*|(\d{3})*)|0?)(\.\d*)?$
```

To test it

```
var r = /^\$?([1-9]\d?\d?((,\d{3})*|(\d{3})*)|0?)(\.\d*)?$/;
var shouldMatch = ["$30,000.00", "30,000.00", "9,000.00", "9000", "1", ".12"];
var shouldntMatch = ["30,000000.00", "1.00c", "19,00.00", "$30,00"];
function test1() {
  for (var i in shouldMatch) {
    if (!r.exec(shouldMatch[i])) {
      alert(shouldMatch[i]);
      return;
    }
  }
}
function test2() {
  for (var i in shouldntMatch) {
    if (r.exec(shouldntMatch[i])) {
      alert(shouldntMatch[i]);
      return;
    }
  }
}
test1();
test2();
```

Comment: I want to accept input with dollar signs and commas.  Yours is too simple.

Comment: In that case you'll want to change the error message. If you describe the format you're aiming for a little better we can figure this out.

Comment: Error message changed at your request.  I want to accept valid US input with dollar signs and commas in the correct places.  $3,000 = valid.  $30,00 = invalid

Comment: +1 thanks for the update.  Came up with my own jScript compliant regex.  Similar to yours but slightly different.  You can see it in update2 of @Ondrej Tucny answer.